# Angular Material Input not updating placeholder text

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 6 with Material CSS from material.angular.io

I am trying to create my directive that will offer translation.

```
<span translate>page.login.btnsubmit</span>
```

is working fine as the text inside tags are getting translated.

To translate the attribute placeholder

**Below is working**

```
<input type="text" translate="placeholder" placeholder="newworld">
```

**Below is not working**

```
<input type="text" matInput placeholder="Username / Email / Mobile" value="" translate="placeholder">
```

It is because of input matInput attribute, that is not taking the updated value.

What are the possibilities i could update the matInput attributes. I action hook i use on directive is ngAfterViewInit

Thanks.

**EDIT 1 - TRANSLATE DIRECTIVE TS**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { TranslateService } from '../services/translate.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[translate]'
})
export class TranslateDirective {

  @Input('translate') referrer:string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private ts: TranslateService) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(_.isEmpty(this.referrer)){ // executed for text between the tags example: <span translate>page.login.username</span>
      this.translateInnerHtml()
    }else{ // executed for attributes
      this.translateAttribute();
    }
    return;
  }

  translateAttribute(){ // Not updating
    this.el.nativeElement.attributes.placeholder.value="dynamic placeholder";
  }

  translateInnerHtml(){ // Working fine as expected
    const innerHtml = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    if (_.isEmpty(innerHtml)) {
      this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'No text provided for translation';
      return;
    }
    this.getTranslationText(innerHtml)
  }


  getTranslationText(text){
    let splitText = _.split(text, '.');
    let key = _.join(splitText.slice(-1));
    let file = _.join(splitText.slice(-2, -1));
    let folder = _.join(splitText.slice(0, splitText.length - 2), '/');
    if (_.isEmpty(key) || _.isEmpty(file) || _.isEmpty(folder)) {
      this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'No text provided for translation';
      return;
    }
    this.ts.get(folder, file).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if (_.isEmpty(data) || _.isEmpty(data[key])) {
          this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'No text provided for translation';
          return;
        }
        this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = data[key];
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**[Adding stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mac3y7)**

Comment: try [placeholder]=" ' ....' " (I put spaces between the quotes to easy read, but you must removed.

Comment: I have added stackblitz code. Can u check into that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the placeholder in a matInput use mat-placeHolder, like

```
<mat-form-field class="username">
     <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="user.username" >
     <mat-placeholder>
        <span translate>page.login.btnsubmit</span>
     </mat-placeholder>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Inside the mat-chip-list together with mat-autocomplete I had to use the translate pipe like this: `[placeholder]="'receivers' | translate"`

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

First of all your code is working fine and setting the `placeholder` of `input` box. What you see on the screen is the `div` `placeholder` created by `matInput` directive.

### Fix

Whenever `matInput` directive is issued, we need to change the `placeholder` `attribute` of `MatInput` so that it will change the `placeholder` `div.

> Follow the steps to change the `placeholder` property of `MatInput`

#### 1. Set the reference of matInput as `#matInput="matInput"`

Set the reference of matInput in html so that it can be accessed in the `translate` `directive`.

```
 <input type="text" matInput #matInput="matInput" placeholder="Original 
     Placeholder" [(ngModel)]="user.username" translate="placeholder">
```

#### 2. Change the `placeholder` of `matInput` model.

Access the `matInput` directive in `translate` directive

```
 @ContentChild("matInput") matInput : MatInput;
```

Change the placeholder of `matInput`

```
this.matInput.placeholder = "Translated placeholder";
```

Working copy is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1ufxj

Comment: Its related to matinput. I am not passing any key but passing translation text as hard coded like. this.el.nativeelement.attributes.placeholder ="newworld"

Comment: It could be issue with text you are trying translate. Can you change `Username / Email / Mobile `to` newworld` and check if works.

Comment: <input type="text" matInput placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="user.username" translate="password">. Kindly note, i am not translating any text, for testing purpose, I am using a static text that replaces existing text in the placeholder attribute. It has nothing to do with the text

Comment: It does make sense now. Could you share the code of `translate` directive.

Comment: I have also created a stackblitz code for your reference

Comment: Updated the answer, working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1ufxj

Comment: use <mat-placeholder> to give the value to the place holder

Answer (score 0):

In my case only something like that helped:

```js
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.setPlaceHolder();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar issue and for the latest angular material version, I could not find  as shared above. The issue for me was with translation not been working in html with translate pipe which eventually got fixed by providing TranslateService in the providers array and providing the following options to TranslateModule

```
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
  isolate: false,
  extend: true,
```